# Простой список но с соединяющим пунктиром вместо элементов списка

Tags: html, css, list, ul, li

нужно сделать примерно как на картинке, но не пойму через что это сделано. В исходном коде копалась, пробовала, но ничего не работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде как сделдано через after, по идее все параметры прописаны там:

```
section.seritem ul li:after {
    content: "";
    width: 20px;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #e8004d;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 13px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Полный изврат, но тем не менее, как варинат. )))

```css
fieldset {
  border-color: red;
  border-style: dashed;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  margin-top: -.5rem;
}

legend {
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% + 1rem);
}

li:last-child fieldset {
  border-left: none;
}

li:not(:first-child) legend {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  color: red;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Эндокринология</legend>
    </fieldset>
  </li>
  <li>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Как повысить...</legend>
    </fieldset>
  </li>
  <li>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Нарушения сна</legend>
    </fieldset>
  </li>
  <li>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Первые признаки</legend>
    </fieldset>
  </li>
  <li>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Рассеянность</legend>
    </fieldset>
  </li>
  <li>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Синдром</legend>
    </fieldset>
  </li>
  <li>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Снижение</legend>
    </fieldset>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Плюсик, но не врубаюсь в семантику.

Comment: Спасибо большое!